# Datastax Cassandra Insert with ifNotExists

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I Have created a keyspace

```
CREATE KEYSPACE xyz WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '1', 'datacenter1': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

I have only two nodes and both DC1 as well as datacenter1 nodes are up. Now when i'm trying to execute an batch of insert statements

```
Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto(keyspace, table).ifNotExists()
.value("home", fieldsToUpdate.getHome())
.value("subCategoryName", fieldsToUpdate.getSubCategoryName())
.value("id", fieldsToUpdate.getId());
batch.add(insert);
session.execute(batch);
```

I get an exception saying

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive)
```

When i remove **.ifNotExists()** clause batch executes without any exception.

Using datastax driver version 2.1.7 .

What should i do to resolve the issue?

Edit:
Nodetool Status

```
abhisheks-MacBook-Pro:bin abhishekagarwal$ sudo ./nodetool status
objc[3398]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.111  19.81 MB   256     ?       f2651124-abdf-486a-a6d7-53327bc2d98c  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.5    5.22 MB    256     ?       d0c72798-1186-4bcb-9e0f-634964a3d083  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

Comment: Could you show the output of "nodetool status".  That would help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have defined the keyspace to keep one replica in 'datacenter1' and one replica in datacenter 'DC1'.  But you don't have a data center called 'DC1', so it is not possible to get a quorum of replicas in the two data centers for the `if not exists` clause.

So you should have defined the keyspace like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE xyz WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '1'}
```